# UIPageViewController's viewController subview animation on transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation, uipageviewcontroller

Is there a way to animate `UIPageViewController`'s viewController subview on transition?

E.g.: I have set `UIPageViewController`'s transition style to Scroll, navigation to Horizontal and spine location to the bottom of the screen.

Each `viewController` of `UIPageViewController` has a label which I want to fade-in or fade-out on transition.

[image: Fade-in and Fade-out on transition]

It is possible to achieve non-animated result by implementing `<UIPageViewControllerDelegate>` protocol. Is it possible to animate the opacity of a label relatively to gesture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not. The delegate doesn't provide any means to get the scroll position. You'll have to roll your own version of UIPageViewController (for example, using a UIScrollView and listen for the scrollViewDidScroll: and other delegate methods)